Variability in computation time for boost::dynamic_bitset's [] Operator with different call sequence
I am seeing variation in compute time for the call to boost::dynamic_bitset's [] Operator on a AWS EC2 instance(Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8375C CPU @ 2.90GHz). In the following code, when the DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC is defined, call takes ~370ms. Whereas, when DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC is not defined, call takes ~1070ms.
Tried following compiler combinations. Results are similar in all cases.
g++ -o perfTestGetDB -O2 -std=c++17 -DDO_COUNT_IN_FUNC perfTestGetDB.cpp
g++ -o perfTestGetDB -O2 -std=c++17 perfTestGetDB.cpp

Here is the code.
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

const int numBits = 1536;
const int setSize = 500;
const int searchSize = 1000000;

void perfTestCountAndGet()
{
#ifdef DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> db1(numBits);
#endif
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> db2(numBits);
    int searchList[setSize];

    // Use the current time as a seed for the random number generator
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 generator(seed); // Mersenne Twister 19937 generator

    // Define the range of random numbers (0 to numBits - 1)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, numBits - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        int idx = distribution(generator);
#ifdef DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC
        db1.set(idx);
#endif
        db2.set(idx);
    }

    // Define another random search index
    for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        searchList[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

#ifdef DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC
    // Perform count
    int count = db1.count();
    std::cout << "Dummy print to prvent optimizing out of the code:" << count << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif

    // Perform the [] operation on dynamic_bitset randonly for setSize
    // for loopSize iterations
    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long int result2 = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < searchSize; l++) {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < setSize; idx++) {
            bool bit = db2[searchList[idx]];
            if (bit) {
               result2 += idx; // Use the bit value in a computation
            }
        }
    }
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2 - start2);
    std::cout << "dynamic_bitset,[]," << duration2.count() / 1000.0L << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dummy print to prevent optimizing out of the code:" << result2 << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
#ifndef DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC
    std::cout << "Check count in main" << std::endl;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> db1(numBits);
    int count = db1.count();
    std::cout << "Dummy print to prevent optimizing out of the code:" << count << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif
    perfTestCountAndGet();
}


Note: The issue is seen only in AWS EC2 instance(Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8375C CPU @ 2.90GHz) and not when tried on a laptop (e.g.: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz)

That's cache effect for you.  Is there an actual question? So far it looks as though you've just shown us something

@sehe, Your answer is elaborated. We are using dynamic_bitset's [] operator in our application and we saw weird behavior in our tests. To reproduce the issue, we wrote above test. I tried the code you mentioned under section "Final Demo" and both options for DoHack produced similar timings. But, I am curious, what minimum change I can make in my program to produce similar results for both cases. I tried using loop variable l in place of idx in expression result2 and did not make any difference.

I'll happily let you figure that out. After all your code cannot be representative (db1, db2 and the whole artificial copying). I just went into detail out of curiosity. I don't claim I understand what you're trying to do. I just know that your question code is highly artificial for the reasons my answer points out. If it doesn't help you find the culprit that's unfortunate

So out of curiosity, I want and simplified this into a proper micro-benchmark:
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>
#include <random>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static constexpr int  numBits    = 1'536;
static constexpr int  setSize    = 500;
static constexpr int  searchSize = 1'000'000;
static constexpr auto now        = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

template <bool DoHack = false>
size_t perfTestCountAndGet() {
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(numBits);
    int                     searchList[setSize];

    auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, numBits - 1), //
                     std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        int idx = dist();
        bits.set(idx);
    }

    // Define another random search index
    std::generate_n(searchList, setSize, dist);

    size_t proof_of_work = 0;
    if constexpr (DoHack) {
        auto db1 = bits; // why?!
        proof_of_work += db1.count();
    }

    // Perform the [] operation on dynamic_bitset randonly for setSize
    // for loopSize iterations
    auto start = now();
    for (int l = 0; l < searchSize; l++) {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < setSize; idx++) {
            bool bit = bits[searchList[idx]];
            if (bit) {
                proof_of_work += idx; // Use the bit value in a computation
            }
        }
    }
    auto d = now() - start;
    std::cout << "dynamic_bitset,[]," << d / 1.ms << std::endl;
    return proof_of_work ;
}

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("normal", [] { return perfTestCountAndGet<false>(); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("with_hack", [] { return perfTestCountAndGet<true>(); })

Which does indeed give a significant advantage for DoHack = true, which is more than a little surprising, because you're not even "warming up" the cache for the bitset, because it counts bits in a copy (db1):

Now, I have to admit I have no clue what the test is actually representing. So looking a the core of the test:
for (int l = 0; l < searchSize; l++) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < setSize; idx++) {
        bool bit = bits[searchList[idx]];
        if (bit)
            proof_of_work += idx; // Use the bit value in a computation
    }
}

I figured a few things weird:

l is not used is just an iteration
idx is iterating all the indexes in searchList
however, what's used in the compution is not that idx, but ... the index into searchList. That seems like a bug, as it may make things very predictable. In fact, we can do the inner loop once, and do proof_of_work += searchSize * (sum_of_inner_loop) instead of iterating.

So let's shift thing a bit around:

leave iteration to the benchmark statistical analysis
idem for the chrono stuff
actually use searchList[idx] instead of idx in the computation
finally, cut the db1 copy (it was cute, because it drove home the point that it wasn't caching/prefetch per se, but it's still a useless copy)

This significantly simplifies the code to
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>
#include <random>

static constexpr int numBits = 1'536;
static constexpr int setSize = 500;

template <bool DoHack> //
size_t perfTestCountAndGet(nonius::chronometer& cm) {
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(numBits);
    int                     searchList[setSize];

    auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, numBits - 1), //
                     std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        int idx = dist();
        bits.set(idx);
    }

    // Define another random search index
    std::generate_n(searchList, setSize, dist);

    size_t proof_of_work = DoHack ? bits.count() : 0;

    cm.measure([&] {
        for (auto probe : searchList)
            if (bool bit = bits[probe])
                proof_of_work += probe;
    });
    return proof_of_work;
}

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("normal", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { return perfTestCountAndGet<false>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("with_hack", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { return perfTestCountAndGet<true>(cm); })

Which still shows the advantage:

However, changing the order of the benchmarks flips that around!

Out on a limb, I wanted to exclude effects from creating and re-seeding the Mersenne Twister:
static auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, numBits - 1), //
                        std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

template <bool DoHack> //
size_t perfTestCountAndGet(nonius::chronometer& cm) {
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(numBits);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
        bits.set(dist());

    // Define another random search index
    int searchList[setSize];
    std::generate_n(searchList, setSize, dist);

    size_t proof_of_work = DoHack ? bits.count() : 0;

    cm.measure([&] {
        for (auto probe : searchList)
            if (bool bit = bits[probe])
                proof_of_work += probe;
    });
    return proof_of_work;
}

And now the difference is gone. Increasing the sample sizes a bit to bring the effect of outliers down:
static constexpr int numBits = 15'360;
static constexpr int setSize =  5'000;

Final Demo
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>
#include <random>

static constexpr int numBits = 15'360;
static constexpr int setSize =  5'000;

static auto dist = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>(0, numBits - 1), //
                        std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));

template <bool DoHack> //
size_t perfTestCountAndGet(nonius::chronometer& cm) {
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(numBits);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < setSize; i++)
        bits.set(dist());

    // Define another random search index
    int searchList[setSize];
    std::generate_n(searchList, setSize, dist);

    size_t proof_of_work = DoHack ? bits.count() : 0;

    cm.measure([&] {
        for (auto probe : searchList)
            if (bool bit = bits[probe])
                proof_of_work += probe;
    });
    return proof_of_work;
}

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("normal", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { return perfTestCountAndGet<false>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("with_hack", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { return perfTestCountAndGet<true>(cm); })



Sanity restored

I still don't think I get what the test is actually representing, but in the off-chance it helps: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2f10fcc00505578

I made the following two small changes to your "Final Demo"
#ifdef DO_HACK_CODE
size_t proof_of_work = DoHack ? bits.count() : 0;
#else
size_t proof_of_work = 0;
#endif
#ifdef DO_HACK_CODE
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("with_hack", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { return perfTestCountAndGet(cm); })
#endif
Ran two combinations
a) g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Inonius-devel/include -DNDEBUG -DDO_HACK_CODE -Wall -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
b) without -DDO_HACK_CODE
Results are a) 57.3024 ms  b) 45.3707 ms & 43.2968 ms

I am running this on AWS EC2 (Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8375C CPU @ 2.90GHz)

I'll do you one better and not involve any metaprogramming at all: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fddf22f8ad4d27e There's definitely something interesting at work here indeed, because this is what it does on my machine: https://i.imgur.com/kTO2Yz4.png o.O Here's me comparing the clang++ assembly side-by-side http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/053c1184-8078-4435-93ad-f098adff2306/2024-04-26 - you can look at it yourself: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/a57f6bec-30ce-42b3-9649-00a3e37bf364/test.cpp.s.xz

Huh. It doesn't appear to matter how the bs is warmed up, but the placement of the warmup call is very sensitive. Now I wonder whether the result is actually correct. https://i.imgur.com/77xZHok.png

Oh wow, I have a new machine. What it seems to show me (besides that upgrading a machine after >10 years is making a huge difference in performance :)) is that the behavior seems very CPU specific. On this Ryzen7 there's no funny business ever, see detailed timings and comparisons using GCC 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.4, 12.3, 13.2 and 14.1 https://imgur.com/a/8vrpgzB Note that my old machine was intel i7-3770K)

I can reproduce the odd behavior that the OP described. (I'm a colleague).
Some additional info:

The time taken to process db1 changes drastically with and without the hack. With the hack (i.e invoke count on db2) it takes 380 ms. Without the hack, it takes 1060 ms.

The odd behavior is seen ONLY when:

there are 2 dynamic bitsets. It's not seen when there's a single bitset variable on which the hack is done (i.e. invoking count()).
both of these must be local variables within a function, called by main. It's not seen when the 2 bitsets are global variables. It's also not seen when they are local variables in the main() function.

So, it's really strange that invoking count() on one bitset object reduces the time to process a different bitset object.
The slightly simplified code is here:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

const int numBits = 1536;
const int setSize = 500;
const int searchSize = 1000000;


void perfTest()
{
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> db1(numBits);
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> db2(numBits); 
    int searchList[setSize];

    // Use the current time as a seed for the random number generator
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 generator(seed); // Mersenne Twister 19937 generator

    // Define the range of random numbers (0 to numBits - 1)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, numBits - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        int idx = distribution(generator);
        db2.set(idx);
    }

    // Define another random search index
    for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
        searchList[i] = distribution(generator);
    }

#ifdef DO_COUNT_IN_FUNC
    // Perform count
    int count = db1.count();
    std::cout << "Dummy print to prvent optimizing out of the code:" << count << std::endl << std::endl;
#endif

    // Perform the [] operation on dynamic_bitset randonly for setSize
    // for loopSize iterations
    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    long int result2 = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < searchSize; l++) {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < setSize; idx++) {
            bool bit = db2[searchList[idx]];
            if (bit) {
                result2 += idx; // Use the bit value in a computation
            }
        }
    }
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2 - start2);
    std::cout << "dynamic_bitset,[]," << duration2.count() / 1000.0L << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dummy print to prevent optimizing out of the code:" << result2 << std::endl << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    perfTest();
}


Didn't see this before. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78382172/variability-in-computation-time-for-boostdynamic-bitsets-operator-with-dif/78387734#comment138455706_78387734? This is your exact code on my new machine: https://imgur.com/a/ViziZ8S Note the difference on Ryzen7 is only the std::cout line.
